# DirectX 7 & VB6 on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vb6, directx

I have a small program in vb6 that uses directx 7. I'm now after 10 years trying to run it on windows 7. Is it possible to run this old program on win 7?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Microsoft knowledge base 
 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971028 
you can't run this program on win7. Having said that you can always run it via 
http://www.virtualbox.org/ 
As far as I know Virtual Box has graphic accelerator support. Hope it helps!